# Is there a way to make an element disappear BEFORE the mousedown event activates?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following snippet, you'll notice that an overlay asks you to 'Click Anywhere', and will add circles to the canvas on `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. Although the overlay text disappears on mousedown, If you click anywhere on the overlay element the canvas doesn't get the mousedown event to draw the start circle.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('target'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', addStartNode);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', addEndNode);

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', hideOverlay);
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', showOverlay);

function hideOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}

function showOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function addStartNode(evt) {
  drawCircle(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 10, 'green');
}

function addEndNode(evt) {
  drawCircle(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 10, 'blue');
}

function drawCircle(x, y, r, c) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = c;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
#target {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: aqua;
}
.node {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  Click Anywhere
</div>
<canvas id="target"></canvas>
```

I thought of just moving the event handler onto a container element or on the `body` element, which would catch the event as it propagates, but sometimes that's just not possible, such as when you're using an [HTML5 game engine](https://html5gameengine.com/) to process interactions.

Does anyone have any clever solutions for this?

## EDIT:

What I really had in mind was a situation where translating the mouse position to the canvas was much more complicated, such as when a game engine or other canvas library is being used. In the following snippet I use [PIXI.js](http://www.pixijs.com/). Note how you can drag the top left and middle bottom nodes, but not the node on the right which is covered by the text.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', hideOverlay);
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', showOverlay);

function hideOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}

function showOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

var nodeRadius = 50;

function Node(x, y) {
  this.g = new PIXI.Graphics();
  this.position.x = x;
  this.position.y = y;
  this.g.node = this;
  this.drawCircle();
  this.g.pivot = new PIXI.Point(nodeRadius / 2, nodeRadius / 2);
  this.g.interactive = true;
  this.defaultPos = new PIXI.Point(this.position.x, this.position.y);
  this.g.on('mousedown', selectNode);
  this.g.on('mouseup', connectNode);
  this.g.on('mousemove', moveNode);
}

Node.prototype = {
  reset: function() {
    this.position.x = this.defaultPos.x;
    this.position.y = this.defaultPos.y;
  },
  drawCircle: function() {
    this.g.clear();
    this.g.beginFill(0x3333FF, 1);
    this.g.drawCircle(0, 0, nodeRadius);
    this.g.endFill();
  },
  connectTo: function(node) {
    this.drawCircle();
    this.g.moveTo(0, 0);
    this.g.lineStyle(5, 0xDDEEFF);
    this.g.lineTo(node.position.x - this.position.x, node.position.y - this.position.y);
  },
  get position() {
    return this.g.position;
  },
  set position(p) {
    this.g.position = p;
  }
};


var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(600, 400),
  container = new PIXI.Container(),
  selectedNode = null;

container.position.x = -150;
container.position.y = 200;
container.scale.x = 0.3;
container.scale.y = 0.3;

var nodes = [
  new Node(700, -500),
  new Node(2200, 50),
  new Node(1500, 450)
];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  container.addChild(nodes[i].g);
}

document.getElementById('content').appendChild(renderer.view);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate() {
  renderer.render(container);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function selectNode() {
  this.node.drawCircle();
  selectedNode = this.node;
}

function connectNode() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    selectedNode.reset();
    selectedNode = null;
  }
}

function moveNode() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    var mousePos = renderer.plugins.interaction.mouse.getLocalPosition(container);
    selectedNode.position.x = mousePos.x;
    selectedNode.position.y = mousePos.y;
    checkCollision();
  }
}

function checkCollision() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i] !== selectedNode && dist(selectedNode.position, nodes[i].position) < nodeRadius * 2) {
        selectedNode.reset();
        selectedNode.connectTo(nodes[i]);
        selectedNode = null;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 580px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.8/pixi.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.8/pixi.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="overlay">
      Drag one node to another
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I purposefully moved and scaled the `container`, because that happens often in games. The canvas itself may be offset from the page and may not even share the same parent as the overlay, which further complicates translating a mouse position to game coordinates.

This is why I was thinking it would be nice to somehow remove the overlay element **before** the `mousedown` event fires, because then we wouldn't have to worry about it.

[**Here is a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rh25nL8w/1/).

Comment: It seems to work "as expected" for me.  What browser/OS are you testing with?

Comment: In my versions of Chrome and Firefox it doesn't add the green circle if you click on the text.

Comment: I explained the logic behind the error, and cFreed actually gave you the full code to solve it. Hope that does it...

Comment: That is essentially the solution I proposed in my question, and mentioned it doesn't always work, such as when you're using a game engine or other library for processing interactions with the canvas. In other words **The logic bound to the canvas mouse events may not be able to be bound to other elements**

Comment: Maybe you could clarify which parts of the code you do and do not control, because otherwise it's difficult to understand the problem (eg. do you control the part which hides the overlay, or the part which draws the circle, does the game engine capture the click event somewhere and you never get it? And which engine do you use, because maybe it has an api that allows you to get the mousedown event?).

Comment: Yeah sorry I guess that isn't clear in the question. I'll update.

Comment: @nus actually, since your answers sufficiently solve the question as proposed here, do you think it would be better to open up a separate question for the game engine specific problem?

Comment: I think you can rewrite the question in place and we'll update our answers...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99356/discussion-between-nus-and-nanowizard).

Comment: I quickly tried to get the new code to run on jsfiddle, but the pixi.js I can find seems to throw an error. From what you describe, if you have a problem that the overlay captures the mousedown event, you can either directly call the event handler of the canvas from there, or if you don't control that one, you can use dispatchEvent to pass the mousedown event on to the canvas. That would almost be like the overlay didn't exist at all. Also if you do control the canvas event handler, and worry about the coordinates, you can use event.screenX instead of clientX to get absolute coordinates...

Comment: Note that it is common practice in JS to sometimes do some coordinate arithmetic, like when you would need coordinates relative to some container rather than absolute coordinates. There is properties like outerWidth which can help you with exact sizes of containers, but that's a jQuery property. In native javascript you can construct it by adding the width + margin +border if I don't mistake...

Comment: the common approach to listen to mouse events on a canvas, is to `var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); var x = evt.clientX - rect.left; var y = evt.clientY - rect.top;` Using this, you just attach one mouse listener of every type on the document itself, and just do a check if it reached the canvas coordinates before executing anything. Attaching many event listeners can be cumbersome for the browser (especially if you also want to attach a mousemove which fires at really high rate), and it is preferred to only attach one on the document and only do the relay into the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115652/nus) comment about using `dispatchEvent` does the trick.

```
document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    renderer.view.dispatchEvent(evt);
  },0);
});
```

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', hideOverlay);
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', showOverlay);

function hideOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}

function showOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

var nodeRadius = 50;

function Node(x, y) {
  this.g = new PIXI.Graphics();
  this.position.x = x;
  this.position.y = y;
  this.g.node = this;
  this.drawCircle();
  this.g.pivot = new PIXI.Point(nodeRadius / 2, nodeRadius / 2);
  this.g.interactive = true;
  this.defaultPos = new PIXI.Point(this.position.x, this.position.y);
  this.g.on('mousedown', selectNode);
  this.g.on('mouseup', connectNode);
  this.g.on('mousemove', moveNode);
}

Node.prototype = {
  reset: function() {
    this.position.x = this.defaultPos.x;
    this.position.y = this.defaultPos.y;
  },
  drawCircle: function() {
    this.g.clear();
    this.g.beginFill(0x3333FF, 1);
    this.g.drawCircle(0, 0, nodeRadius);
    this.g.endFill();
  },
  connectTo: function(node) {
    this.drawCircle();
    this.g.moveTo(0, 0);
    this.g.lineStyle(5, 0xDDEEFF);
    this.g.lineTo(node.position.x - this.position.x, node.position.y - this.position.y);
  },
  get position() {
    return this.g.position;
  },
  set position(p) {
    this.g.position = p;
  }
};


var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(600, 400),
  container = new PIXI.Container(),
  selectedNode = null;

document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    renderer.view.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }, 0);
});

container.position.x = -150;
container.position.y = 200;
container.scale.x = 0.3;
container.scale.y = 0.3;

var nodes = [
  new Node(700, -500),
  new Node(2200, 50),
  new Node(1500, 450)
];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  container.addChild(nodes[i].g);
}

document.getElementById('content').appendChild(renderer.view);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate() {
  renderer.render(container);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function selectNode() {
  this.node.drawCircle();
  selectedNode = this.node;
}

function connectNode() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    selectedNode.reset();
    selectedNode = null;
  }
}

function moveNode() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    var mousePos = renderer.plugins.interaction.mouse.getLocalPosition(container);
    selectedNode.position.x = mousePos.x;
    selectedNode.position.y = mousePos.y;
    checkCollision();
  }
}

function checkCollision() {
  if (selectedNode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i] !== selectedNode && dist(selectedNode.position, nodes[i].position) < nodeRadius * 2) {
        selectedNode.reset();
        selectedNode.connectTo(nodes[i]);
        selectedNode = null;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 580px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.8/pixi.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.8/pixi.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="overlay">
      Drag one node to another
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that it needs to be done in a timeout or you get an `InvalidStateError` since "the event is already being dispatched".

Answer (score 0):

Adding an eventlistener to the overlay as well should fix your problem:

```
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener('mousedown', addStartNode);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('target'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', addStartNode);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', addEndNode);

document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener('mousedown', addStartNode);

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', hideOverlay);
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', showOverlay);

function hideOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}

function showOverlay() {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function addStartNode(evt) {
  drawCircle(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 10, 'green');
}

function addEndNode(evt) {
  drawCircle(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 10, 'blue');
}

function drawCircle(x, y, r, c) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = c;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
#target {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: aqua;
}
.node {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  Click Anywhere
</div>
<canvas id="target"></canvas>
```

Comment: Just to remark the obvious, we both answered this in a way 'that works', but why add code if you can achieve the desired result by removing code. The less code you have, the less code can have bugs, the less you need to read to understand what's going on, the less you have to maintain... The OP has a logic error, no need to add stuff to 'patch it up'. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble up in the hierarchy of the dom. Since your 'hideOverlay' is an event on the body, the top most element, it won't bubble up to canvas. It would have to bubble down, which it doesn't. Since the overlay is positioned absolute, it's not inside the canvas, so a click on it won't bubble up to the canvas.

In short, the simple solution is to just have one event handler on a mousedown, eg body.mousedown which means you want to do the same thing where-ever the event takes place on the screen, namely hiding the overlay and drawing a circle on the canvas, so don't complicate things by having two event handlers. In body.mousedown, hide the overlay, and draw a circle.

Btw your code would also work as expected if you just call addStartNode from hideOverlay, but why would you?

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use a unique event detection for each mouse event.

So first dropping the `canvas.addEventListener()`s, then gathering show/hide overlay and draw blue/green circle, like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('target'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

function mouseDown(evt) {
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
  drawCircle(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 10, 'green');
}

function mouseUp(evt) {
  drawCircle(evt.clientX, evt.clientY, 10, 'blue');
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function drawCircle(x, y, r, c) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = c;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}
```